# How to increase size of JRadioButtons & JCheckBoxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jradiobutton

I have a checklist with radio buttons and check boxes, I want to make the circles and boxes little bigger than their default size.

Comment: Are you using a LayoutManager? If so, which one?  More info, please.

Answer (score 3):

Some platforms support a large size variant, as discussed in [*Resizing a Component*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide custom Icons. Read the API for the appropriate methods to set custom icons for the various states of the model.