# Making JButtons equal size using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to know if it is possible to set the size of `JButton` components in a `GridBagLayout`, I want my to Buttons "Start" and "Quit" among each other, and I want to make them bigger, the size is irrelevant, I want to know the general procedure.

I tried different things I found on the Internet (using other layouts) but it just ended with more errors.

```
public class Display implements Runnable
{

    public Display()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,700));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createComponents(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createComponents(Container cont)
    {

        GridBagLayout pane = new GridBagLayout();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Quit");

        button1.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        button1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);


        cont.setLayout(pane);
        cont.add(button1);
        cont.add(button2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Display d = new Display();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(d);

    }
}
```

[How it should look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcIbE.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Use GridLayout if you want the components to all be the same size. Remember that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager.

Comment: `GridBagConstraints#fill`?

Comment: That's a big frame for just two buttons. Do more components need to go in there? Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the (entire) GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. `button1.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));` A layout manager will more likely honour the preferred size than the size, but don't set that either, since the preferred size will be no better than a guess.

Comment: You might also like to have a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), one of the first examples looks like it doing what you want

Comment: Posible duplicate of [*How to increase size of JRadioButtons & JCheckBoxes?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6258402/230513)

Comment: I edited my post with a picture how it should look like

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. As mentioned by HFoE, this is well suited to a single column `GridLayout` Provide some layout component spacing and add a largish empty border to the panel that contains the button, and the job is done.*"and I want to make them (buttons) bigger"* There are a number of ways to make buttons larger. e.g. 1) Set a larger font. 2) Call `setMargin(Insets)` to add more space around the text. 3) Use a large icon. 4) Make the text longer (for more width). The 3rd and 4th ways are quite arbitrary.

Comment: What @AndrewThompson said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by *Hovercraft Full Of Eels*, this is well suited to a single column `GridLayout`. A grid layout makes all components the same size. Provide some layout component spacing and add a largish empty border to the panel that contains the buttons, and the job is done.

> ..and I want to make them (buttons) bigger

There are a number of ways to make buttons larger. e.g.

1. Set a larger font.
2. Call `setMargin(Insets)` to add more space around the text.
3. Use a large icon.
4. Make the text longer (for more width).

The 3rd and 4th ways are quite arbitrary.

---

This example uses the first two, as well as an empty border around the buttons to provide further white-space.

[image]

Check the comments in the code for details.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ButtonColumnLayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String[] labels = {"Start", "Stop", "Quit"};
    // adjust numbers to change spacing between button text and button edge
    Insets insets = new Insets(10,40,10,40);

    ButtonColumnLayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        // adjust last two numbers to change spacing between buttons
        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        // adjust numbers to change border around buttons
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40,100,40,100));

        for (String s : labels) {
            ui.add(getBigButton(s));
        }
    }

    private final JButton getBigButton(String text) {
        JButton b = new JButton(text);
        // adjust float value to change font size
        b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont(25f));
        b.setMargin(insets);

        return b;
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                ButtonColumnLayout o = new ButtonColumnLayout();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```